# create a script to Insert Posts from mysql into wp_posts

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to migrate a table with current data (posts) into my new WordPress site.

1. What is the best way to export my data so I can easily insert/import it into the WordPress table? CSV or JSON or something else?
2. How can I properly write the script to make the necessary mapping changes between columns?

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts(post_author, post_date, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_status, post_name, post_modified, post_parent, post_type)

SELECT AuthorId, CreatedDate, Content, Title, Excerpt, Status, Slug, ModifiedDate, ParentId, ContentType

FROM
```

In the from will i include path for json/csv file or should i paste the rows of data that i want?

ATTEMPT:
I tried the following sql command with a single json object for testing but i get these two errors:

Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '(@json) with(AuthorId INT, PublishDate DATETIME(6), Content LONGTEXT, Title' at line 3

```
SET @json := '{
    "Id" : 1003,
    "ParentId" : null,
    "AuthorId" : 1,
    "MediaId" : null,
    "Title" : "DO NOT PUBLISH - The New Kid on the Block",
    "SubTitle" : "Subtitle text same",
    "Excerpt" : "Excerpt sample text",
    "Content" : "<p>Testing content text</p>",
    "Status" : "Trashed",
    "Slug" : "the-new-kid-on-the-block-duplicated",
    "ContentType" : "Post",
    "SuppressFromFeed" : "0",
    "PublishDate" : null,
    "CreatedBy" : "@TODO",
    "CreatedDate" : "2019-09-05 00:02:06.233819",
    "ModifiedBy" : "Admin User",
    "ModifiedDate" : "2021-02-22 22:16:27.944033",
    "IsSearchable" : "1",
    "CustomLabel" : null}';
INSERT INTO wp_posts(post_author, post_date, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_status, post_name, post_modified, post_parent, post_type)
SELECT AuthorId, PublishDate, Content, Title, Excerpt, Status, Slug, ModifiedDate, ParentId, ContentType
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    with(AuthorId INT, PublishDate DATETIME(6), Content LONGTEXT, Title VARCHAR(250), Excerpt VARCHAR(150), Status VARCHAR(20), Slug VARCHAR(250), ModifiedDate DATETIME(6), ParentId INT, ContentType VARCHAR(20));
```

Comment: if you have access to both DB's at the same time why not write a php script that loops through the posts you need (don't forget about _postmeta), then create new posts in the new DB, keep in mind parent assoc in heirarchy; If you have WP CLI installed even easier...
Failing that look into plugins like WP IMPORT/EXPORT ALL (https://www.wpallimport.com)

Comment: @BarrieDawson is this possible if only one of the sites is wordpress? The other is a different web application - I want to write a script that will take my posts from my old site and insert it into my new WordPress site.

Comment: Aboloutley, and simple, just build up your SQL and get your query data and loop creating each post/page; check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Answer (score 0):

```php
$postInsertedIds = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE SOMETHING = 'baz';";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $result['title'],
        'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => array( 8,39 ),
    );
 
    // Insert the post into the database.
    $postInsertedIds[] = wp_insert_post($my_post);
}
//debug output the inserted id's
var_dump($postInsertedIds);
```

Comment: How will i run this? Where will i place this to have it execute?

Comment: The above makes the presumption that all the tables are stoedd in the same DB, if not you'll need to use a secondary connector ie: mysqli to gather the data;
As for execution you have several choices, personally I'd install WP CLI and write a command that executed this from terminal: https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/commands-cookbook/

Comment: Excuse my ignorance as i am learning the ropes for wordpress but lets say i have a csv with all the data i want to insert into wordpress and i use the code you wrote and i want to pull data from the csv and save each row as post.. who do i go about running the command in wp cli? I just installed wp cli and looking around how the commands are used.

Comment: Would i add the function in functions.php for my theme?

Comment: I tend to put scripts like that in an mu-plugin, that way it has visibility over any theme currently in use and is automaticaaly loaded (plus looks neater if your folder architecture is important to you lol) to run the command (if installed by composer) /vendor/bin/wp *your-command* (replace with your registered command without the asterisks)